leading coefficient of a polynomial generating the extension of an ideal
I am reading the section about localizations in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra, and having some doubts on a proposition.

Let $S$ be an integral domain with fraction field $F$ and let $A$ be a nonzero ideal in $S[x]$. Suppose $AF[x]=(h(x))$ where $h(x)$ is a polynomial in $S[x]$ with leading coefficient $a\in S$. Let $S_a$ be the localization of $S$ with respect to the powers of $a$. Then
(1) $AF[x]\cap S[x]=AS_a[x]\cap S[x]$​, ...
Proof: We first show that $AF[x]\cap S_a[x]=AS_a[x]$. Since $S_a\subseteq F$, the containment $AS_a[x]\subseteq AF[x]\cap S_a[x]$ is immediate. Suppose that $f(x)\in AF[x]\cap S_a[x]$. ..... we see that $f(x)$ can be written as a polynomial in $S_a[x]$ times $h(x)$, so $f(x)\in AS_a[x]$. .....

To make things clear, let $D_S=S\setminus\{0\}$ and $D_a=\{\,a^n\,|\,n\geqslant0\,\}$. Then $F=D_S^{-1}S$ and $S_a=D_a^{-1}S$. So $AF[x]=D_S^{-1}A$ and $AS_a[x]=D_a^{-1}A$.
In the proof, the authors have shown that $f(x)$ can be written as a polynomial $g(x)$ in $S_a[x]$ times $h(x)$. To show that $f(x)=g(x)h(x)\in AS_a[x]$, it remains to prove $h(x)\in AS_a[x]$ so that $g(x)h(x)\in g(x)(AS_a[x])\subseteq AS_a[x]$ since $AS_a[x]$ is an ideal of $S_a[x]$.
However, I can not give the proof of $h(x)\in AS_a[x]$ unless replacing the condition "$a\in S$" by "$a\in A$" in the proposition: Let $AF[x]=\langle h(x)\rangle$ where the leading coefficient of $h(x)$ is $a\in A$. Suppose the contrary: $h(x)\not\in AS_a[x]=D_a^{-1}A$, then $\forall\,p(x)\in A$, $\forall\,n\geqslant0$, $p(x)/a^n\neq h(x)$. And since $S$ is an integral domain, it is $p(x)\neq a^nh(x)$. So $A\cap D_ah(x)=\varnothing$. But then $a\in A$ implies that $h(x)a^n\in h(x)A\subseteq A$ in $S[x]$, i.e., $A\cap D_ah(x)\neq\varnothing$, a contradiction.
So, is it a typo in the proposition of writing $a\in A$ incorrectly as $a\in S$?
